# Wireless mouse not working while travelling

Tags: windows-10, wireless-mouse, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm travelling and I brought my surface pro 4 laptop with me and a wireless mouse (+receiver) and the mouse does not work. The pointer does not move at all.

It's this type:

[image]

It did work briefly when I started up a game. But as soon as I shut it down, no mouse movement anymore. When starting the game again, no effect. Hasn't worked since.

The blue and green lights of the mouse are on, so I have power. The only real difference I can think of is that I didn't bring the accompanying wireless keyboard as well.

The native touchpad from the surface keyboard does work (just not as comfortable).

Anything I can do to fix this?

I'm on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Have you always used it with the keyboard before? It can be that both are connected to the same receiver.

Comment: @MátéJuhász It was a same-package purchase, so yes.

Comment: Do you have only that one receiver plugged into your computer? (Do you use docking station?)

Comment: @MátéJuhász Receiver only, I have no docking.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Device Manager (Windows + R, type **devmgmt.msc**) and seeing if the mouse is recognised by the PC?

I assume you've got the little wireless dongle/reciever with you

Comment: Its been working fine at home for quite a while, so it should be recognized. It is relatively old and has 'experienced' a lot. Batteries are fairly new, maybe its just worn ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this wireless mouse with it before? I remember running into a similar issue when Microsoft Surface tablets were brand new and there was a known issue with wireless USB mice. At the time, the problem was solved by switching to a Bluetooth mouse.

Comment: I have as long as I own the Surface. About 2 years. Has been working fine until now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a solution to the question,  should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It just kept on not working, so when I happened to pass a computer shop, I bought a new mouse. Thanks for the response.